# Xamarin forms PCL Splash screen not working on Android 12 and above

Tags: xamarin.forms

Due to the change of the splash screen API in Android 12 and above, our xamarin forms application for android is not displaying the splash screen anymore.

On research I can see some alternative way to display the splash screen but these are all specific to Xamarin.Android not xamarin.forms.

Has anybody recently fixed the splash screen problem on android?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate suggests using

```
val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
```

but there is no equivalent code for this on C#.

I tried creating a separate folder called values-v31 and created a styles.xml file and updated the file with the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">       

    <!-- Set the theme of the Activity that directly follows your splash screen. -->
    <!-- Required -->
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/SplashScreen</item>
</style></resources>
```

But I am getting below errors on the compile time.

[image]

Does anybody has a work around for this problem?

I am using below specifications for testing.
xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2478
Android API 31

Comment: Create an activity with the splash as the entry point of your app and then inside that activity navigate to the main activity.

Comment: @FabriBertani What do you mean by creating an activity? Will you please clarify it? I already have a splash screen but due to the API changes in Android 12, it's not working with it.

Comment: I did a test with the official  sample [Xamarin.Android - Creating a Splash Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/splashscreen/), and it works properly on my android emulator(android 12).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the nuget Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.SplashScreen. The equivalent code for val splashScreen = installSplashScreen() is AndroidX.Core.SplashScreen.SplashScreen.InstallSplashScreen(this) in the OnCreate of your MainActivity before base.OnCreate(). You can find a Xamarin.Android example called NavigationGraph5 using the Xamarin Application Icon at the following link https://github.com/gmck/NavigationGraph5. Even though it is not a forms project I don't see any reason why the same code wouldn't work in a forms project.

Under no circumstances do not try and add a separate Activity as SplashScreen - see Google's documentation.

Comment: This is the problem. I can't find this package on NuGet to add to the Android project. Somehow the package is not compatible with the forms project

Comment: Make sure you check Include Pre Release when you search for it.

Comment: Thank you. Ticking the pre-release did find the package